# How to fix my function that checks for a full board in my tic-tac-toe game

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to build a tic tac toe game and I'm having trouble with making a working function to check if the board is full. my list for the board is
`board = [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']`
and my function is

```
def fullBoard():
"""Returns a boolean value reporting the state of the board, full or not.
True for full, False for not full."""
for y in board:
    if board[y] == ' ':
        return False 
        print(False)
        break

else:
    print(True)
    return True
```

what I want it to do is search each item in the list and when it finds a ' ' or space, it returns false and breaks the loop. but if there is no ' ' it returns true meaning the board is full (I put the print functions in just for my sake while I was trying to fix the darn thing.)

I thought this would work but I get TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str  refering to my `if board[y] == ' ':` line. If anyone knows how to get this to work the way I want that would be great. Also take note I'm only in comp prog 1 and am at a very basic level, so simplicity would be best. (also please don't try to make it shorter or run faster. I just want to know what the mistake I've made is so I can learn from it.) Thank you very much!

Comment: Another option is to avoid coding the loop yourself by using the `in` or `not in` operator (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) in the Python manual). In Python 2, there were also more generalized functions `reduce`, `all`, and `any` that you could use when you're checking for something more complex than the presence/absence of a particular value. I imagine they're still available in Python 3 somewhere, but I think I remember something about `reduce` as a global function being deprecated for being unintuitive.

Answer (score 2):

It's even easier than what you are doing.  The misunderstanding is in your `for` loop.  When iterating over a list, the value of `y` is not the index of the the item in your `board` list, it is the **value** of each item.

So:

```
for y in board:
    if y == ' ':
        return False

return True
```

The source of your confusion probably comes from the fact that, when iterating over a python dict using a for loop, the variable (in this case `y`) would in fact be the dictionary key.  And then you'd need to use the key to access the value at that position in the dictionary.  But that's for a dictionary.. you have a list.  Hence no need for that.

But there's an even quicker way to do it:

```
    if ' ' in board:
        return False
    return True
```

That's it.. no `for`, no nothing.  Python's `in` operator tells you if a value is contained within a list (or certain other types).

If you want to get even more minimal.. just:

```
return not ' ' in board
```

That's it.. just one line of code.  The way it works is.. `' ' in board` has a value of `True` if any of the items in `board` are a space, or `False` if there is no item with a value of space in board.  But you want a value of `False` if there is a space, `True` if not.. so by putting `not` in front, you invert the value.. making the True into False and vice versa.

Since you are learning, it's not necessarily good to take this minimal approach but I figured I would add it to my answer so that you would understand better how python handles these things.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the loop (for y in board) y is already the element in board list and you do not need to index it (board[y]). Simply replace board[y] with y and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Also, the `else` is not needed and will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simpler one:

```py
def space_check(board):
    '''
    Returns True if the board is full
    and Returns False if the board is not full
    '''
    for y in board:
        if y == ' ' or y == '': 
            return False

    return True
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is completely correct, but for one thing. See how board isn't a dictionary, but a list? Lists don't have key/value pairs.

Here's the fixed code:

```
def fullBoard():
   for y in board:
       if board[y] == ' ':
           return False 
       else:
           return True
```

Comment: This will incur same problem as the OP

Comment: How can it work with 
`board = [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']`